# What is the prior corresponding to a weighted sum of pdfs?

Tags: regression, distributions, hierarchical-bayesian

Recently, I have read a paper (Bayesian Bridge Regression
, H. Mallick, 2018) which states that since
$$
\frac{\lambda^{1/\alpha}}{2\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}e^{-\lambda|\beta|^\alpha}=\int_{u>|\beta|^\alpha}\frac{\lambda^{1+1/\alpha}}{2u^{1/\alpha}\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}u^{(1+1/\alpha)-1}e^{-\lambda u}du
$$

then hierarchical representation is as follows

$$
\beta|u\sim \text{Uniform}(-u^{1/\alpha},u^{1/\alpha})
$$
$$
u\sim \text{Gamma}(1+1/\alpha,\lambda)
$$

My question: Suppose that instead
$$
\frac{\lambda^{1/\alpha}}{2\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}e^{-\lambda|\beta|^\alpha}=\int_{u>|\beta|^\alpha}\frac{\lambda^{1+1/\alpha}}{2u^{1/\alpha}\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}(c_1 f(u)+c_2 g(u))du
$$

where $f$ and $g$ are two known pdfs and $c_1,c_2$ some constants. Then, how would we write the hierarchical representation? and are there any problems with this kind of representation?

Comment: In your given integral, you are integrating with respect to $\mathbf{u}$ but the range of the integral is given for $\beta$. I don't understand that. Also, the integral is of the form $f(\beta|u)\Pi(u)$. In order to write the hierarchical representation as you asked, you neeed to find $f(\beta|c_1f+c_2g)$ and $\Pi(c_1f+c_2g)$. I don't think you can just plug in any pdf into the hierarchical model without knowing how they are obtained in the first place. also you just omitted the parts of $f(\beta|u)$ and replaced them with $c_1f+c_2g$. Why is that?

Comment: You omitted the parts of $\Pi(u)$, not $f(\beta|u)$

Comment: @DebayanKoley, the integration is on $(|\beta|^\alpha,\infty)$

Comment: @DebayanKoley, you are the right $\beta\sim$ should be $\beta|u\sim$.

Comment: @DebayanKoley, "also you just omitted the parts of $f(β|u)$ and replaced them with $c1f+c2g$. Why is that?" I was just wondering what happens of we found that instead of the gamma pdf there was two known pdfs, for example two gamma densities with different parameters.

Comment: The expression will be simply $\int_{u>|\beta|^{\alpha}}\frac{c_1f}{2u^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}+\frac{c_2g}{2u^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}$. But the question remains what are the random variables associated with f and g? If $\mathbf{u}$ follows pdf of $c_1f+c_2g$ then we can use their convolution in the resulting hierarchical expression.

Comment: @DebayanKoley, suppose that $
c_1 f+c_2 g=c_1 u^{a_1-1}e^{-b_1 u}+c_2 u^{a_2-1}e^{-b_2 u}
$  how would the hierarchical representation change?

Comment: The title question should be edited into *What is the prior corresponding to a weighted sum of pdfs?* or something like that. The first comment shows a potential confusion into seeking a prior for $x_1f+c_2g$.

Answer (score 0):

The integral representation
$$\int_{u>|\beta|^\alpha}\frac{\lambda^{1+1/\alpha}}{2u^{1/\alpha}\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}(c_1 f(u)+c_2 g(u))\,\text du$$
involves unnecessary terms $\lambda^{1+1/\alpha}$  and $\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)$ and should rather be written as
$$\int\frac{\mathbb I_{u>|\beta|^\alpha}}{2u^{1/\alpha}}\times[c_1 f(u)+c_2 g(u)]\,\text du\quad \text{with}\quad c_1+c_2=1$$
meaning that
\begin{align}
\beta|u&\sim \text{Uniform}(-u^{1/\alpha},u^{1/\alpha})\\
u&\sim c_1 f(u)+c_2 g(u)
\end{align}
a mixture of two distributions. Which can be rewritten as a three level hierarchical model:
\begin{align}
\beta|u&\sim \text{Uniform}(-u^{1/\alpha},u^{1/\alpha})\\
u|z=1&\sim f(u)\qquad u|z=2\sim g(u)\\
z &\sim c_1^{\mathbb I_{z=1}}c_2^{\mathbb I_{z=2}}
\end{align}

A trivial mixture that produces the same Gamma marginal on $\beta$ is
$$c_1 f(u) + c_2 g(u) = \frac{\lambda^{1+1/\alpha}}{\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}u^{(1+1/\alpha)-1}e^{-\lambda u}\mathbb I_{u<\mu} + \frac{\lambda^{1+1/\alpha}}{\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}u^{(1+1/\alpha)-1}e^{-\lambda u}\mathbb I_{u>\mu}$$
for an arbitrary $\mu$.

Comment: If we suppose that $u\sim c_1 Gamma(a_1,b_1)+c_2 Gamma(a_2,b_2)$, then how do we ensure that the integral equals one?

Comment: I mean how do we ensure that the integration of the probability of $u$ equals one.

Comment: could you please explain how \begin{align}
u|z=1&\sim f(u)\qquad u|z=2\sim g(u)\\
z &\sim c_1^{\mathbb I_{z=1}}c_2^{\mathbb I_{z=2}}
\end{align} works?

Comment: Check the keywords `mixtures of distributions` `mixture models` `latent variables` and `EM algorithm`